My Bluetooth headphones work only mono (no stereo)
I'm currently using Ubuntu 24.04, but I also faced this issue in version 22. When I connect my Bluetooth headphones (Soundcore P3), it plays only mono and the only available configurations in the settings are:
-HSP/HFP
-HSP/HFP codec CVSD
-HSP/HFP codec mSBC
I've tried almost every solution I could find, but nothing has worked. Has anyone else encountered this problem and managed to solve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
There was a previous post with a similar problem and an answer suggests to turn off input channel to allow A2DP. I tried that, but the problem is still existing and I still have only these 3 configuration above...
PS: I use my earbuds with different systems (i.e. Android, iPad, Windows, other distros like fedora) and it works well without any problem.

This question is similar to: Bluetooth headset only plays sound in mono. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is finally solved! Here's what worked for me:

Remove pipewire and bluez with all configurations:
sudo apt remove --purge pipewire bluez


This will likely cause errors and your system's GUI may stop working. Don't worry!

Restart Your System

Reinstall pipewire, bluez, and Ubuntu Desktop:
sudo apt install pipewire bluez ubuntu-desktop^


Start the GUI: If the GUI doesn't start automatically, you can manually start it with:
startx


Restart Again

Hope this helps!

Be wary before using this solution, as it may break the system as OP indicated. You will likely have to manually fix things on the Command Line after executing commands.
